# Why is the 1 mH (inductor) in this design? What happens if I probe at 23/54 to measure CURRENT without having the 1mH?

Tags: inductor

[image]

I need to MEASURE the CURRENT at 23 and 54.
I don't see the 1 mH in the schematic. Do I need to add that?
What happens if I probe for current without the 1 mH?
What does the 1 mH do to the circuit?
Will I damage the card if the 1 mH is not present while checking for current?

would It be safe to measure -0.4A to +0.4A across pin 23?
[image]

Comment: Yoke is another term for coil or inductor.

Comment: I thin k they're telling you that the Horizontal Yoke Coil has 1mH inductance.

Comment: Why don't you see the 1mH inductor in the schematic. You even marked it yellow.

Comment: sorry, thats from another picture. i shouldve made it looked different.

Comment: You do realize that the current through that inductor is going to be some kind of wonky AC, right?  A normal ammeter won't do you much good.

Comment: The horizontal yoke is part of the coils that sit around the neck of a CRT. The circuit will not function as intended without the yoke or equivalent inductor. So measuring as in your second diagram would not yield what you are after.

Answer (score 1):

If you measure current by shunting yoke, then you short out the current supplied by R90 (0.249Ω). n.g. so just keep yoke connected and sense current on pin 50 via R101.

To operate without an Hcoil may not damage these parts, but it won't work as required. Beware of HV Flyback transformer for Hsweep.

The circuit is designed to deliver a controlled current sawtooth ramp to drive the yoke with a linear sweep.  The amount of current is determined by the yoke defection power coefficient given in mH*A^2 for peak current which is also dependent on coil inductance.

Normally the ramp of current is sensed and compared outside this cct. to correct the linearity of an integrated pulse current in a polystyrene cap normally. This is not the complete circuit.

Comment: my specific instruction is to determine the HORIZONTAL YOKE DRIVE, level -0.4A to +0.4A at pin 23. the image above I added, would that do the job or do I measure current at pin 50 and R101 as you sugguested?